# How do I make the cells change colour one at a time rather than all at once?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have this grid and I need to make the cells 'light up' in a specific order I have managed to get them to change to the colours I need but they all change colour at the same time. And I also need it to loop e.g. the first one changes to yellow then back to grey and then it doesn't change again until all of the other cells have cycled through. The order I need is Yellow, Green, Blue, White, Orange.

Comment: you could use `setTimeout` with different intervals for each colour within your current `setInterval`...

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using CSS keyframe animations? You would need to figure out all the timings and then animate each of the cells background colors to change to the desired color and back again. [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) has a good page about it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `setInterval` individual for each cell. Modify your function `changeCol()` so it takes a cel (instead of looping through each cell).

Then you create a foreach loop to make a call for each cell setting the interval after a `setTimeout()` function.

The key is to initiate the `setInterval()` for each cell at a slightly different time. That's why you use the `setTimeout(fn(), i*delay)`.

```
//for each cell {
    setTimeout((setInterval(changeCol(), 1000)), i*delay);
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `changeCol` to the following.. you can play with the value `100` to set the delay for the `setTimeout`

```
var changecol = function() {
    var i = 1;
    $.each(colourinfo, function(tileid, colarray) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('#' + tileid).css('background-color', colarray[count % colarray.length]);
        }, i * 100);
        i++;
    });
    count++;
};
```